# What is the difference between the quantum fluctuation, the zero point energy and the cosmological constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, cosmological-constant

I have difficulty to understand the real difference between those three concepts of the energy of the vacuum it's self.( **Quantum fluctuation, the zero point energy and the cosmological constant.**)

I saw here in this question: [Is the term "quantum fluctuation" an aide to understanding?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441144/).

That for an expert in quantum theory, the quantum fluctuation is the same as the kinetic energie of the zero point value. I also fund in the same question, a link from the same persone who refere this page to understand the problem for non-expert :

https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/quantum-fluctuations-and-their-energy/

Where this theoretical physicist seems to says that the quantum fluctuation is the same as the cosmological constant.

I cannot belive that these three concepts refer to the same thing. 
So I am a bit lost in this emptiness.

Answer (score 3):

Equating the zero point energy with the cosmological constant is a common misconception shared even by the most sophisticated physicists.

However, the zero point energy and the cosmological constant are totally different animals.

The energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}_\Lambda$ of the cosmological constant is of the form:
$$
T^{00}_\Lambda = \rho_\Lambda, 
$$
and
$$
T^{11}_\Lambda = T^{22}_\Lambda = T^{33}_\Lambda= p_\Lambda
$$
with
$$
p_\Lambda = -\rho_\Lambda.
$$

And what does the zero point energy look like? Take a massless fermion for example, the vacuum energy-momentum tensor $T^{\mu\nu}_F$ can be calculated as (see details [on page 55 here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08907)):
$$
T^{00}_F = \rho_F = -\frac{2\hbar}{(2\pi)^3}\int k d^3k, 
$$
and
$$
T^{11}_F = T^{22}_F = T^{33}_F= p_F = -\frac{2\hbar}{3(2\pi)^3}\int k d^3k
$$
Therefore, with a proper regularization/cutoff, one has
$$
p_F = \frac{\rho_F}{3}
$$
which is categorically different from the case of cosmological constant $p_\Lambda = -\rho_\Lambda$.

**Hence there is no similarity between the zero point energy and the cosmological constant at all!**

In cosmological nomenclature
$$
p = w\rho
$$
where $w$ is called equation of state parameter, which is $-1$ for the cosmological constant and $1/3$ (radiation-like) for the above massless fermion example. Changing to massive fermion/boson will not help the case either (interested reader is encouraged to verify independently).

---

Added note.

Some may challenge the above calculation. To corroborate the notion let's quote another paper (page 12) [Everything You Always Wanted To Know About The Cosmological Constant Problem (But Were Afraid To Ask)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3365);

> It is clear from the previous expressions that $p/\rho \neq -1$ which indicates that the stress energy tensor is not
> of the form ∝ $-\rho g_{\mu\nu}$. In the limit m → 0, as can be
> easily shown from Eqs. (75) and (78), the equation of
> state is in fact $p/\rho = 1/3$. This would mean that the
> zero point fluctuations do not behave like a cosmological
> constant but rather like radiation.

The paper goes on to discuss how to fix this with dimensional regularization. But the dimensional regularization usually kills off non-logarithmic divergences and the divergent integral in hand is quartical, so I am not particularly convinced.

---

More added note.

Let's look at the fermion kinematic Lagrangian (ignoring mass term) in curved space time:
$$
L_{F} \sim \bar{\psi}e\wedge e\wedge e\wedge d\psi
$$
where $e$ is the vierbein/tetrad/frame 1-form and $\wedge$ denote wedge product between differential forms.

And what does the cosmological constant Lagrangian look like? it's
$$
L_{\Lambda} \sim e\wedge e\wedge e\wedge e
$$

As you can see, if the zero point energy of the fermion can be somehow equated to the cosmological constant, you have to magically convert $e\wedge e\wedge e\wedge d$ to $e\wedge e\wedge e\wedge e$, which is **mission impossible**.

BTW, note that the Higgs potential is of the form:
$$
V_{H} \sim (-m_H^2 |\phi|^2 + \lambda |\phi|^4) e\wedge e\wedge e\wedge e
$$
which may indeed contribute to cosmological constant, should the Higgs field $\phi$ develop a non-zero VEV upon spontaneous symmetry breaking. Mind you that the Higgs potential contribution is a separate story from the zero point energy ppl usually talk about.

Comment: Thank you for this response. So I have to assune that the zero point enery is the same as the quantum fluctuation?

Comment: @Doodger24, the quantum fluctuation is a broader concept than the zero point energy. For example, when you calculate a scattering diagram, the virtual particles in the quantum loops are created out of quantum fluctuation.

Comment: As mike stone writes in comments to an answer to [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529388/vacuum-energy-cancellation/529390#comment1196868_529390), “The vacuum is a Lorentz-invariant quantum state, so its energy-momentum tensor has to be a numerically invariant tensor under Lorentz transformations. The only possibility is a multiple of $g_{\mu\nu}$.” This implies $p=-\rho$. I think this argument is correct and therefore the paper you cite must be incorrect and this answer is wrong.

Comment: @G.Smith, see added note.

Comment: Your note has added to my conviction that your answer is wrong. I especially object to your first sentence. The idea that the vacuum energy must be Lorentz invariant is completely mainstream, and the notion that it actually isn’t is the fringe view.

Comment: I agree that vacuum energy is Lorentz invariant. But we are talking about zero point energy, right? The whole discussion is about whether we can equate vacuum energy with zero point energy.

Comment: The mainstream point of view as I understand it is that zero-point energy is the energy of the field when there are zero quanta present, and, when zero quanta are present, we call that state the vacuum. So what distinction do *you* see between “zero-point energy” and “vacuum energy”?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the discussion is about the relationship between these and the cosmological constant.

Comment: Dear @G.Smith, I can not devine whether your preferred definition of "vacuum energy" is more "zero-point energy"-like or more "cosmological constant"-like, since I am not omniscient and human beings have free will and etc. My post per se is only about the distinction between "zero-point energy" and "cosmological constant".

Comment: I do not believe that mainstream physicists draw any distinction whatsoever between vacuum energy and zero-point energy. They are *synonyms*. You have already agreed that the vacuum energy-momentum tensor *must* be Lorentz invariant. To insist that the zero-point energy-momentum tensor is *not* Lorentz-invariant is a fringe view, caused merely by incorrect regularization.

Comment: But obviously there are four people besides you who (perhaps) hold this view.

Comment: Dear @G.Smith, 'nough said. Let's enjoy the wonderful world the Almighty created for all of us.

Comment: Your proposed vacuum energy-momentum tensor is not Lorentz invariant, because the regularization you choose is not Lorentz invariant. Why do you call it a "proper" regularization then?

Comment: @Javier, just like you, I prefer Lorentz invariant calculations if possible. please, by all means, go ahead and offer a Lorentz invariant regularization which can handle the quartical divergences and prove that ZPE and CC are of the same form. I would be supper happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is the so called lamda cdm model where the cosmological constant is einstains equation is the constant minimal  energy density of empty space responsible for expansion of the universe.