# Vacuum energy cancellation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, vacuum

The quantum field theory predicts that vacuum energy should manifest as a repulsive field.

At the same time, vacuum energy should be gravitationally attractive.

So, attraction and repulsion should to an extent cancel each other. Why we cannot explain the small value of cosmological constant with this cancellation?

Comment: Haven't you got repulsive and attractive the wrong way round here? The cancellation doesn't happen in any easy way because gravity is so much weaker than the other forces.

Comment: What is the Nature of the repulsive field? Gravitational?

Comment: Neither of your two initial claims make any sense to me. Can you justify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The net source  of gravity (i.e the effective "mass density"  in weak field Poisson's equation) is $E+3P$ where $E$ is the energy density and $P$ the pressure (these have the same units). The Lorentz invariant vacuum energy-momentum tensor  of dark energy has 
$$
T_{\mu\nu}={\rm diag}(E,P,P,P) =E\, g_{\mu\nu} = E\, {\rm diag}(1,-1,-1,-1).
$$
 This means that    $P=-E$ so the negative $P$ outweighs the positive and attractive $E$ to give an efective "mass" density of $-2E$ -- i.e repulsion.

Comment: The question is why $P=-E$. This is **assumed** to explain dark energy.

Comment: It's the Energy-momentum of the *vacuum*. The vacuum is a Lorentz-invariant quantum state, so its  energy-momentum tensor has to be a numerically invariant tensor under Lorentz transformations. The only possibility is  a multiple of $g_{\mu\nu}$. This means that $P=-E$.

Comment: @mikestone This argument, which seems right to me, seems to contradict [this recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529136/what-is-the-difference-between-the-quantum-fluctuation-the-zero-point-energy-an/529147#529147) to another recent and related question. That answer references a paper on arXiv. Do you think that that paper is wrong?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article I cited below it is said that this is an assumption.to give an explanation of what dark energy is.

Comment: Well the linked another answer says the zero point energy is a different beast and should be gravitationally attractive. So, it should cancel some more of tge dark energy repulsion.

Comment: The vacuum state does appear to be the same for all observers. We would have Lorentz vilating effects if it were not. However we reguarize/renormalize the infinite vacuum energy it should still be invariant and therefore $P=-E$. Thus I think that the linked paper is wrong.  It reads rather polemically, which is never a good sign.

Comment: BTW the idea that positive $E$ (and hence negative $P$) leads to repulsion seemed obviously wrong to me at first. I heard Alan Guth expound his ideas at a conference just after he published them in 1980. I  thought that surely he had gotten his sign wrong. But, no, he was correct.

Answer (score 1):

QFT predicts an infinite value of the quantum vacuum energy (or less if we don't count the energies above the Planck energy). The biggest false prediction ever. Obviously, this can't be the case (as one can observe easily). However, renormalization comes to the rescue, which tames the vacuum energy. The cut-off energy is the Planck energy.

So the vacuum energy is zero. But, as one can read in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy) about the quantum vacuum:

> Quantum theory of the vacuum further stipulates that the pressure of the zero-state vacuum energy is always negative and equal in magnitude to ρ. Thus, the total is ρ + 3p = ρ − 3ρ = −2ρ, a negative value. If indeed the vacuum ground state has non-zero energy, the calculation implies a repulsive gravitational field, giving rise to an acceleration of the expansion of the universe. However, the vacuum energy is mathematically infinite without renormalization, which is based on the assumption that we can only measure energy in a relative sense, which is not true if we can observe it indirectly via the cosmological constant.

Mark that it's written: **If** indeed the vacuum ground state has non-zero energy. **If**, which means one isn't sure, but it can serve as an explanation for dark energy.

See also [this](https://phys.org/news/2019-10-quantum-vacuum-energy.html) article for further information.