# Cosmological constant (CC) vs vacuum energy density (VED)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

How are the two different? I know that CC has negative pressure and opposes gravity. But what about VED? Is VED supposed to have positive pressure and cause gravity too?

Comment: Zero point energy has positive pressure. See related question/answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529136/what-is-the-difference-between-the-quantum-fluctuation-the-zero-point-energy-an/529147#529147